# unknown column 'xyz' in where clause

Tags: mysql

I know this question has been asked lots of times - and I've read all the answers to post I can find, but none of them are the same as my particular issue.

I've imported some member details into a new table called 'importmems', which has the following fields:

MemID, MemNo, RefID, etc (the other names aren't relevant)

I'm trying to update the MemNo field in the original 'members' table using the following query:

```
update members
set MemNo = importmems.MemNo
WHERE importmems.MemID = members.MemID
```

I get the error saying there is no column 'importmems.MemID' - even though there is!

MemID is the PK in the members table, if that makes any difference

Any help much appreciated

Thanks
Chris

Comment: MySQL does not lie! If it refers to an "unknown column" than there is no such column. Can you post the `show create table tbl_name` output for both tables?

Answer (score 0):

You have not inluded `importmems` in the table list:

```
update members
join importmems on importmems.MemID = members.MemID
set members.MemNo = importmems.MemNo
```

See [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: Thanks Bohemian - I didn't realise you had to join the tables first!